# Using PHP in HTML pages without messing up Character Encoding

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I'm using various php codes in most of **html** files from our website. I want html files treated as php, thefore I've added this line to the .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .php
```

Now, everything is fine, my html files evaluate the php code and i am happy. However my happiness was short lived because this solution created another problem. Character Encoding got messed up and now although i declared

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

characters are being displayed like this on the website

> c�nd �ncearc? s? �?i scad?

**My question is how can i evaluate php in the html files and NOT messing up my Character Encoding of the Html pages.**

---

Requested to show code:

```
<h1 class="Normal-P"><span class="Normal-C-C0">&quot; Cele </span><span class="Normal-C-C1">3 MARI GREŞELI</span><span class="Normal-C-C0"> pe care majoritatea le fac atunci când încearcă </span></h1>

<h1 class="Normal-P"><span class="Normal-C-C0">să îşi </span><span class="Normal-C-C1">scadă colesterolul în mod natural </span><span class="Normal-C-C0">&quot;</span></h1>
```

results in this

**Click pe butonul din stanga jos pentru redare....Asteapt? c�teva secunde p�n? cand acest video se �ncarc?**

Comment: How PHP files themselves are encoded?

Comment: they are also also encoded in utf-8

Comment: Ok, can you show the particular code that creates the shown text (or the parts around it)?

Comment: I updated the question above, you can see the code there that creates the text @raina77ow

Comment: @RaduS Try an `ISO-8859-1` encoding, see if that helps.

Comment: i tried ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-2 and no result

Comment: @RaduS You may also have a [**byte order mark issue**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) it's a possibility and should not be left out of the equation.

Comment: @RaduS In your `.htaccess` file, try adding this `AddCharset UTF-8 .html` and `AddCharset UTF-8 .php` and `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: @RaduS I think what the problem may be now, is the type of editor you are using. I created a file with plain Windows Notepad, and it did not show the characters correctly. However, when I pasted my codes into Notepad++ and saved it as "Encoding/Encode in UTF-8 with or without BOM", it displayed correctly. Visit http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ to download it if you wish. That's the best advice I can give you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank a lot Fred, it is true, i also notice now that the files are "UTF-8 with BOM" that is very strange indeed cause i never heard of this encoding before

Comment: @RaduS You're welcome. I learned that lesson the hard way also. Has your problem been resolved?

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSS FINALLLLYYY i am happy, now it's good, i will change all files in the entire website now. THANNKK you @Fred You are my god today and saved my ass also :)

Comment: @RaduS I saw that now, that is great news! I'm glad this matter was resolved, cheers (*Peace*) You are very much welcome, I was happy to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what the problem may be now, is the type of editor you are using.

I created a file with plain Windows Notepad, and it did not show the characters correctly.

However, when I pasted my codes into Notepad++ and saved it as "Encoding/Encode in UTF-8 without [**BOM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)" (byte order mark), 
it displayed correctly.

**Visit [notepad-plus-plus.org](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to download it. It has different encoding formats.**

Comment: Thank you Fred, i just finished correcting all files...it was a painful process but worth it ;)

Comment: @RaduS That's great news. Yes I agree it is a lot of work, that is why I like to use `includes` as navigation menus, etc., so I only have 1 file to edit if I need to modify something globally. I take care of some rather large websites and I would not be happy to edit 100's of files per server. All the best, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your HTTP Content-Type header needs to also set UTF-8 explicitly.

To do that without modifying your files, in your php.ini, add/change

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Alternatively, right before you're about to send output, in PHP, do:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
```

Example start of an HTML file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Comment: thank you @boen_robot I tried the first variant in the php.ini and it didn't help or maybe i didn't do it right. I want to implement the second suggestion you mentioned but i don't quite understand where specifically you want me to put the line `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: At the top of HTML files, before any content (including DTD and whitespace), within a "\<?php" block. I've edited the answer above with a more complete example.